# Entify Frame work not saving data using code first - asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-6

I am new to EF and need to make change to existing with EF in asp.net webform 4.5

I am able to show data in repeater control, pull data in dropdown but for some reason i am not able to save data for Employee, I dont get any error and when i creck SQL Profiler theit it doesnt show any Insert stored procedure in the list of details it shows.

Am i doing something wrong or my approach is wrong

```
 App_Code

    DBClass
    Department.cs
    Employee.cs
    EmployeeDBContent.cs
    EmpRepository.cs
```

Code for all the files

**EmployeeDBContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using empNS;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for EmployeeDBContext
/// </summary>
/// 
namespace empNS
{
    public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
    {


        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }


        public EmployeeDBContext()
            : base("EmployeeDBContext")
        {
            //disable initializer
            Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeDBContext>(null);
        }


    }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //}


}
```

**EmpRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for EmpRepository
/// </summary>
/// 

namespace empNS
{
    public class EmpRepository
    {

        public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            return empDBContext.Employees.ToList();
        }

        public static List<Department> GetDepartments()
        {
            EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            return empDBContext.Departments.ToList();
        }


        public static List<Department> GetDepartmentNames()
        {
            EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            return empDBContext.Departments.ToList();
        }

        public static void  InsertEmployee(Employee employee )
        {

            EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            empDBContext.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

**Department.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Dept
/// </summary>
/// 
namespace empNS
{
    public class Department
    {

        //Scalar properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**employee.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Emp
/// </summary>
/// 
namespace empNS
{
    public class Employee
    {
        //Scalar Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }

        public int Department_Id { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        [ForeignKey("Department_Id")]
        public Department Department { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**Employee.aspx**

```
 <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptEmpList" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p><%#Eval("Id") %> | <%#Eval("FirstName") %> | <%#Eval("LastName") %></p>



            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <h1>SAVE EMPLOYEE</h1>
        <p>FN: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>LN: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Des: <asp:TextBox ID="txtDes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Dept: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDept" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></p>

        <p><asp:Button ID="btnSaveEmployee" runat="server" Text="Save Employee" OnClick="btnSaveEmployee_Click" /></p>
```

**Employee.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using empNS;


public partial class EmployeePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    Employee empObj = new Employee();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptEmpList.DataSource = EmpRepository.GetEmployees();
        rptEmpList.DataBind();

        //fill DD
        getDepartmentNames();
    }


    public void getDepartmentNames()
    {
        ddDept.DataSource = EmpRepository.GetDepartmentNames();
        ddDept.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddDept.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddDept.DataBind();
    }
    protected void btnSaveEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        empObj.FirstName = txtFN.Text;
        empObj.LastName = txtLN.Text;
        empObj.Designation = txtDes.Text;
       empObj.Department_Id = int.Parse(ddDept.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
       EmpRepository.InsertEmployee(empObj);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your InsertEmployee function does not do anything (especially not with the given employee). You have to add it to the context's DbSet.

Comment: You mean this `public static void  InsertEmployee(Employee employee )
        {

            EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            empDBContext.SaveChanges();
        }`

Comment: you InsertEmployee function missing a line   `empDBContext .Employee.Add(employee );` before `SaveChanges();`. Also i think you should wrap in the intentation of EmployeeDBContext  with [using statment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
public static void  InsertEmployee(Employee employee )
{    
    EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
    empDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Needs to be this:

```
public static void  InsertEmployee(Employee employee )
{    
    EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
    empDBContext.Employees.Add(employee);
    empDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT**

Make sure that you have your DbSets declared properly as well.
In your case it should be something like:

```
DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Comment: When i add it i get error `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'empNS.EmployeeDBContext' does not contain a definition for 'Employee' and no extension method 'Employee' accepting a first argument of type 'empNS.EmployeeDBContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: empDBContext.Employee**s**.Add(employee);

Comment: Yes i figure it out it needs to be `Employees`. appreciated

Comment: Editted my answer

Comment: I think my DbSet is declared like you have mentioned in my code ` public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } unless you didnt mean something else

Comment: If you can see that empDBContext.Employees is available and or suggested aka you don't have any error's this means everything is OK and that means that you indeed have it already declared :)